# Magento 2 Install Admin Issue

Tags: magento2, installation

I've been working through the issues one by one.  I now have this message when after the admin login:
Magento 
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 349068 bytes) in `/home/rxxxxx3/public_html/shop/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Json/JsonFile.php on line 92`
Any idea where to go next?

Comment: When is this error coming ?

Comment: I can reach the admin login, this comes after I enter name+password.

Comment: You can increase the memory limit using .htacess .
php_value memory_limit 512M in your .htaccess file in the Magento root

Comment: Is the site hosted on a shared hosting or a dedicated server?

Comment: It is a shared server from Lunarpages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configured Memory limit in following places:

1. In php.ini

   > `memory_limit = 512M`
2. In .htaccess file

   > php_value memory_limit 512M

Comment: Thank you - I had been told to raise it to 64m, which I did, but apparently 512M is the correct number.  Solved